# Scala: Restricting traits mixing-in f-bounded polymorphic traits

Tags: scala, self-type, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have:

```
trait Pet[T <: Pet[T]] {    //disallows: Dog extends Pet[String]
  self: T =>                //disallows: Dog extends Pet[Monkey]
  def rename(s: String): T
  def name: String
}
```

Now a trait like `Feline` that would extend the `Pet` class can be easily added as follows:

```
trait Feline[T <: Feline[T]] extends Pet[T] {
  self: T =>
  def pur : Unit = println("purrrr")
  def scratch: Unit
}
```

But if I were to introduce a type mixing in `Pet` with a self-type such as:

```
trait PetCareInfo[T <: PetCareInfo[T]] {
    self: T with Pet[T] =>
    def registerPet: Unit
  }
```

I get the error:

> > type arguments [T] do not conform to trait Pet's type parameter bounds [T <: Pet[T]]

my understanding is that this is because self-type check in `PetCareInfo` looks at the types `A with B` individually and as such fails the restriction. (not sure if this is a bug or feature)

I can use existential types instead:

```
type TypeRestriction: Pet[A] forSome {type A}

trait PetCareInfo[T <: PetCareInfo[T]] {
    self: T with TypeRestriction => //mix-in restriction
    def registerPet: Unit
  }
```

and that would kinda work. Two questions:

1. I cannot directly define the the existential type at the mix-in restriction line. I get:

> > ; expected but 'forSome' found.

Is there a way of getting around this?

2. In practice the `PetCareInfo`'s `forSome` restriction + `Pet`'s own restriction means that I can not have:

   `class Cat extends Pet[Dog] with PetCareInfo[Cat]`

But I would like to know if there is a way of not depending on `Pet` for this.

**Update**:

For question 2, I can change the existing type restriction to be:

```
type Restriction[T] = A with Pet[A] forSome {type A <: PetCareInfo[T]}

trait PetCareInfo[T <: PetCareInfo[T]] {
  self: Restriction[T] =>
  def registerPet: Unit
}
```

and that seems to be solving the problem. Although, there is still no guarantee that the structural `A` type will be the same as `T`, so we are still depending on `Pet`. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
trait PetCareInfo[T <: Pet[T] with PetCareInfo[T]] {
  self: T =>
  def registerPet: Unit
}

abstract class Cat extends Feline[Cat] with PetCareInfo[Cat] // OK
abstract class Dog extends Pet[Dog] with PetCareInfo[Dog] // OK
abstract class Tiger extends Feline[Tiger] with PetCareInfo[Cat] // Error.
```

**Update**: The above demonstrates an *is a* relationship. That is, `Cat` both *is a* `Feline` and *is a* `PetCareInfo`. Here's an alternative that makes `PetCareInfo` a member of `Pet`, so that a `Cat` *has a* `PetCareInfo`. (I'm assuming that this makes sense. You could equally have a `Pet` member of `PetCareInfo` if that's more appropriate.)

```
// Change of emphasis: T is type of Pet. OK since we're in charge of its definition.
trait PetCareInfo[T <: Pet[T]] {
  // Etc.
}

trait Pet[T <: Pet[T]] {
  // Etc.
  val info: PetCareInfo[T]
}

abstract class Dog extends Pet[Dog] {
  // Etc.
  override val info = new PetCareInfo[Dog] {
     // Define a what a PetCareInfo looks like for a dog.
  }
}
```

This latter approach could also be used to hide `PetCareInfo` (if the `info` member was `private`), in the event that such details are not useful to the code user.

**UPDATE 2**: BTW, regarding the error "`type arguments [T] do not conform to trait Pet's type parameter bounds [T <: Pet[T]]`" for:

```
trait PetCareInfo[T <: PetCareInfo[T]] {
  self: T with Pet[T] => // <- Error
  def registerPet: Unit
}
```

the message is self-explanatory: `Pet`'s `T` must be derived from `Pet[T]`; however, you have only defined a `T` for `PetCareInfo` to be derived from `PetCareInfo[T]`, and a `PetCareInfo[T]` has no expressed relationship to a `Pet[T]`. The `self` declaration simply constrains the type of any concrete `PetCareInfo` instance, and cannot be used to change the definition of what a `T` represents.

That is, `T` must be derived from `PetCareInfo[T]` and `self` must belong to an object that extends `T with a Pet[T]`. However, since `T` is not derived from `Pet[T]`, it's impossible to create such an instance, hence the error. So, it's not a bug but an essential type check.

Comment: Nice, I forgot that we could restrict the parameterisation type too! :) yeah that would do. So, let's step back for a second. Check out my update. How do these structures compare in terms of is-a and has-a relationships?

Comment: If you're trying to mixin capabilities, then this will be an _is a_ relationship. You could achieve a _has a_ relationship by, for example, creating an overridable `PetCareInfo` member of `Pet`, so that concrete `Pet`s had to create a suitable `PetCareInfo` member. Your update is just another way of expressing the relationship that `PetCareInfo` instances need to mixin a `Pet` (albeit the other way around compared to my example: `PetCareInfo with Pet`, instead of `Pet with PetCareInfo`. _Dotty_ (aka _Scala 3_) would make that ordering redundant, by allowing `Pet & PetCareInfo`.

Comment: yeah wrong expression sorry. I meant "is a functionality for" vs "is a". mix-in vs inheritance basically. In your example, the `T` we parameterise `PetCareInfo` with, is required to extend both `Pet` and `PetCareInfo`, or be them essentially. In my example, `T` should be only a `PetCareInfo` as per normal f-bounded poly logic. Its relationship with `Pet` however is one of "having access to it". I think the conclusion from above is that we could have `has access to "a" Pet[T]` but this won't necessarily be `''the" Pet[T]` with the same `T`.

Comment: It can't be the same `T`, unless you declare `T` as I did to be derived from both traits. Your `Restriction[T]` adds a new type `A` and requires that `A` be derived from both traits. So they're equivalent in terms of creating a concrete `PetCareInfo` instance - the concrete class must still extend both traits. However, by declaring `T` to be derived only from `PetCareInfo[T]`, you're not being up-front about that requirement.

Comment: You've expressed a desire to declare `PetCareInfo[T]` without being dependent upon `Pet`. However, you also seem to want to make your implementation of `PetCareInfo[T]` dependent upon `Pet`. So either implement `PetCareInfo` so that it doesn't depend upon `Pet`, or accept that the dependency does, in fact, exist.

Comment: So the distinction between the two versions is that one leaks the abstractions from `Pet` and one doesn't. In your version, we could add a method to the trait like: `def getName(t: T) = t.name` whereas in my version, you can't, which is useful for maintainance reasons . This is however not what you want if you want the `PetCareInfo[T]` to actually have access to the fields of `Pet[T]` for example when the trait is to provide some generic method in the `PetCareInfo` trait. In that case, yours is the way to go.

Comment: If you don't want to reference `Pet` from anything in `PetCareInfo`, why do you even need to declare existential types or restrict the `self` type in `PetCareInfo`?

Comment: `PetCareInfo` could be a collection of text/animation (which could be implemented externally and simply mixed-in the concrete Pet) or more generally, a set of functions that the concrete Pet implements using its field variables.

Comment: as for why I have not picked your solution as the answer yet, it's because there is two parts to the question. Also I am still getting my head around the subject matter. Downvote was a bit harsh! :)

Comment: So, by the sound of it, `PetCareInfo` doesn't access `Pet` in any way shape or form, isn't dependent upon `Pet` and `PetCareInfo.self` is only dependent upon itself. So why the complexity of using existential types and insisting upon `self` being dervived from `Pet`? BTW, I didn't downvote your question. ;-)

Comment: I mean, if you need `PetCareInfo` in a concrete `Pet` instance, you could obviously just mix it in. But, it appears that `PetCareInfo`'s implementation doesn't actually depend upon `Pet`, so far as I can tell. It appears that you're simply trying to limit use of `PetCareInfo` to `Pet` instances. Correct? Why is that restriction necessary?

Comment: good question! Well this is all a bit abstract, but maybe an alternative way of having "type families" in Scala? and erm, thanks for the upvote! :D I appreciate the discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156279/discussion-between-mike-allen-and-shs).